# How to calculate the minimum cost to convert all n numbers in an array to m?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have been given the following assignment:

> Given N integers in the form of A(i) where 1≤i≤N, make each number
>   A(i) in the N numbers equal to M. To convert a number A(i) to M, it
>   will cost |M−Ai| units. Find out the minimum cost to convert all the N
>   numbers to M, so you should choose the best M to get the minimum cost.
>
> Given:
>
> ```
> 1 <= N <= 10^5
>
> 1 <= A(i) <= 10^9
> ```

My approach was to calculate the sum of all numbers and find `avg = sum / n` and then subtract each number by `avg` to get the minimum cost.

But this fails in many test cases. How can I find the optimal solution for this?

Comment: Where does this task come from?

Comment: Sounds like homework, maybe you should post your attempt so people help you better.

Comment: It was given as a assignment problem!

Comment: The word "integers" is significant, I believe.

Comment: Guys, he has a homework and he has an approach. Why did you downvote his question?

Comment: super, can you show us an example test case where your approach fails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take the median of the numbers (or either of the two numbers nearest the middle if the list has even length), not the mean.

An example where the mean fails to minimize is: [1, 2, 3, 4, 100]. The mean is 110 / 5 = 22, and the total cost is 21 + 20 + 19 + 18 + 78 = 156. Choosing the median (3) gives total cost: 2 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 97 = 101.

An example where the median lies between two items in the list is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 100]. Here the median is 3.5, and it's ok to either use M=3 or M=4. For M=3, the total cost is 2 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 2 + 97 = 103. For M=4, the total cost is 3 + 2 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 96 = 103.

A formal proof of correctness can be found on [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318381/on-a-1-d-line-the-point-that-minimizes-the-sum-of-the-distances-is-the-median), although you may convince yourself of the result by noting that if you nudge M a small amount delta in one direction (but not past one of the data points) -- and for example's sake let's say it's in the positive direction, the total cost increases by delta times the number of points to the left of M minus delta times the number of points to the right of M. So M is minimized when the number of points to its left and the right are equal in number, otherwise you could move it a small amount one way or the other to decrease the total cost.

Answer (score 0):

@PaulHankin already provided a perfect answer. Anyway, when thinking about the problem, I didn't think of the median being the solution. But even if you don't know about the median, you can come up with a programming solution.

I made similar observations as @PaulHankin in the last paragraph of his last answer. This made me realize, that I have to eliminate outliers iteratively in order to find `m`. So I wrote a program that first sorts the input array (vector) `A` and then analyzes the minimum and maximum values.

The idea is to move the minimum values towards the second smallest values and the maximum values towards the second largest values. You always move either the minimum or maximum values, depending on whether you have less minimum values than maximum values or not. If all array items end up being the same value, then you found your `m`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getMinCount(vector<int>& A);
int getMaxCount(vector<int>& A);

int main()
{
    // Example as given by @PaulHankin
    vector<int> A;
    A.push_back(1);
    A.push_back(2);
    A.push_back(3);
    A.push_back(4);
    A.push_back(100);

    sort(A.begin(), A.end());

    int minCount = getMinCount(A);
    int maxCount = getMaxCount(A);

    while (minCount != A.size() && maxCount != A.size())
    {
        if(minCount <= maxCount)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < minCount; i++)
                A[i] = A[minCount];

            // Recalculate the count of the minium value, because we changed the minimum.
            minCount = getMinCount(A);
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < maxCount; i++)
                A[A.size() - 1 - i] = A[A.size() - 1 - maxCount];

            // Recalculate the count of the maximum value, because we changed the maximum.
            maxCount = getMaxCount(A);
        }
    }

    // Print out the one and only remaining value, which is m.
    cout << A[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}

int getMinCount(vector<int>& A)
{
    // Count how often the minimum value exists.
    int minCount = 1;
    int pos = 1;
    while (pos < A.size() && A[pos++] == A[0])
        minCount++;

    return minCount;
}

int getMaxCount(vector<int>& A)
{
    // Count how often the maximum value exists.
    int maxCount = 1;
    int pos = A.size() - 2;
    while (pos >= 0 && A[pos--] == A[A.size() - 1])
        maxCount++;

    return maxCount;
}
```

If you think about the algorithm, then you will come to the conclusion, that it actually calculates the median of the values in the array `A`. As example input I took the first example given by @PaulHankin. As expected, the code provides the correct result (3) for it.

I hope my approach helps you to understand how to tackle such kind of problems even if you don't know the correct solution. This is especially helpful when you are in an interview, for example.